# Pasteurize egg yolks?

Tags: eggs, lemon-juice, condensed-milk

I want to make a cake filling consisting of sweetened condensed milk and lemon juice so I thought of adding egg yolks to make it more dense, but the condensed milk and lemon juice doesn't need cooking then should I cook them over a double boiler? if so, up to what temperature? Or there is other way in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I would look for a lemon custard recipe as that's pretty much what you want to do...